# I written an ERC20 token contract, now I have to use my token in another contract for transaction amount. How?

Tags: erc-20, metamask, inheritance

Taking help of openzepplin, in making ERC20 token , I now have to use this token in multiple contracts for various use.

So, how do I code my ERC20 token into other contracts, so that at time of amount transfer, metamask will send tokens ( not eth).

Any query, please do let me know & I'll share immediately.

Comment: Please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 1):

You can import IERC20 interface from OpenZepplin to use with your token address:

```
import {IERC20} from "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract Test {

    function foo() public {
        // Reference to deployed token
        IERC20 token = IERC20(0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000023);

        // Obtain sender balance
        uint256 funds = token.balanceOf(msg.sender);

        // Transfer from sender
        token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), funds);
    }
}
```

Note: You should be aware that Test contract is making the call, so inside the token `msg.sender` is Test contract.